# page break css working fine in internet explorer 8 but not in firefox and google chrome

Tags: asp.net, html, css, panel, page-break

i got stuck in an issue i.e. i wrote following css for showing page breaks in my html but i am facing the problem that it works fine in the Internet explorer but not working in firefox and chrome below is the inline css i applied

```
 <br style="page-break-after: always;">
```

below is my HTML code

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlHide" runat="server" Visible="false">
                    <br style="page-break-after: always;">
                </asp:Panel>
```

**nb**:above line is in asp:panel control of asp.net which renders as DIV in html

any suggestions to change the css are welcome. I will wonder if anybody could plz help me.

Comment: "Note that page-break-after may not work with <BR> or <HR> tag in some browsers." taken off [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/pagebreak.shtml)

Comment: Also, i don't think <br> tag is a block element. and page-break-after only works on block elements like BLOCKQUOTE, BODY, CENTER, DD, DIR, DIV, DL, DT, FIELDSET, FORM, Hn, LI, LISTING, MARQUEE, MENU, OL, P, PLAINTEXT, PRE, UL, and XMP.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any floats, remove them from the css while printing, floats may be the issue and page-break may not be the issue at all.

Comment: after removing the floats also the problem is not solved i tried with <br/> and empty div both but it does not make any sense.though thanks for the answer